# Force specific network interface in Java with HttpClient 4.5

Tags: java, networking, routes, httpclient, vpn

On my linux machine I have a physical network interface `eth0` and an virtual interface called `tun0` which is provided by a VPN connection.

I have different options to set network routes, either by directing all traffic through `eth0` or `tun0`. I want to keep `eth0` as the default route but want my Java application to send specific HTTP requests through `tun0`.

So with established VPN connection my network routes look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.200.196.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

This is my code for a HTTP GET request:

```java
NetworkInterface nif = NetworkInterface.getByName("tun0");
Enumeration<InetAddress> nifAddresses = nif.getInetAddresses();

String host = "https://api.ipify.org?format=json";
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setLocalAddress(nifAddresses.nextElement()).build();
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();) {
    HttpGet req = new HttpGet(host);
    req.setConfig(config);
    try (CloseableHttpResponse resp = client.execute(req)) {
        byte[] bs = EntityUtils.toByteArray(resp.getEntity());
        System.out.println(new String(bs));
    }
}
```

When I do this, my request times out.

I have no knowledge about the IP addresses I want to request. So it is not possible to just adjust the routes so that a certain address range is routed via VPN.

Is it even possible to do what I want or is ignoring routes something the kernel forbids?